# Execute MSI package as User administration using WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created MSI package using Wix.

Wix Script:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

<CustomAction Id="InstallDRV" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]setup.exe" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />
```

This 'setup.exe' will be installing 'Printer' drivers and set as default printer.

So, this will be update the default printer in the below key.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows

But, msiexec.exe is running in 'System Administrator' instead of 'User Administrator'.

How can we execute MSI as 'User Administrator' account.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Dileep

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for per machine "Everyone" installs to run with the system account so that they can run elevated. Also, there is little support in Windows Installer for running elevated custom actions with the installing user's credentials. The way that people solve this problem is primarily to do this kind of "install within an install" in some other way that does not involve custom actions. But try this:

1. The custom action needs to be impersonate="yes" so that it impersonates the installing user.
2. Elevate the entire MSI install by starting from an exe that elevates to administrator privilege and then starts the MSI.

Comment: How to pass User's credential to custom action to run as current user.

Comment: That's what the answer describes. Impersonate = yes and elevate the entire MSI install by running it as administrator or from an elevated process.

Comment: I have used the InstallScope="perMachine". Then it asks UAC prompt. Following error is displayed while executing MSI package.

Comment: Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: InstallDRV, location: C:\Users\SDILEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIPKG_1601a\, command: C:\Users\SDILEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIPKG_1601a\setup.exe

Comment: As it says, 1721 means that a custom action failed. Is there evidence that this is caused by not having admin privilege? You know that it is not because of a missing dependency? It's not clear to me why you saw that error and posted an issue related to admin privilege because a deferred custom action with InstallScope elevated in a per machine install WILL run elevated. Also that error can't be diagnosed without knowing what your settings were in that case. It may be better for you to start another question to find out why you get error 1721.

Comment: If user specifies custom action with Impersonate = yes, that custom action will run with Current User permissions. If current user is non-admin, this error is displayed.

Comment: Your last comment is confusing. Your WiX source has installscope=per-machine and you comments say you see a UAC prompt. Therefore the install requires elevation, therefore a non-admin can't run the install anyway. Your custom action is deferred, therefore it is in the execute sequence. That means a non-admin can't even run the install and get past the UAC elevation that is shown before deferred custom actions run. If non-admin users are getting the error BEFORE the UAC prompt then you have custom actions in the UI sequence that are failing because they require elevation.